How to wire a 3 way lamp with keyless bulb that has 3 screws and 4 wires
I took apart a vintage lamp that has a night light bulb on the bottom of lamp and a bulb on top. I didn't take the wires off the switch and don't know how to put the wires back on. There are 4 wires, black, white and a regular cord that is brown with 2 wires, ribbed and smooth. The socket has 3 screws, silver, one that looks Cooper and the other looks gold. Does any one know which wire goes where?

Can you post a picture?

I don't know how

Lamps that have two bulbs that operate like this: bulb-1 ON; bulb-2 ON with bulb-1 OFF; bulb-1 and 2 ON; all off. These are not called "3-way". There is a 2-circuit switch that operates them, so saying (or thinking) 3-way can be misleading. It is a "2-circuit" lamp. NOTE: the upper bulb socket may indeed be a "3-way" socket, in addition to the 2-circuit lamp setup...

I don't understand.  You "didn't take the wires off the switch," so why is there a problem with "how to put the wires back on?"
